# Linear Equation in 4 variables- No of solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

`If 3a+6b+9c+4d = 100  and a ,b,c and d are natural numbers , then how many values d can take?`

How to approach this type of problem?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Restriction: $d\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)$.

Answer (score 2):

As $3,6,9$ are multipliers of $3$, then $$3|(3a+6b+9c).$$
It is known that $$100\equiv 1 (\bmod 3).$$
So, $d$ must be $$d\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)$$ to fit modular equation $$3a+6b+9c+4d\equiv 1 (\bmod 3).$$

As $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb N$, then $4d\le100-3-6-9=82$, so

- $d\equiv 1 (\bmod 3)$
- $1\le d \le 20$.

Then there are only these values for $d$:
$$1,4,7,10,13,16,19.$$

Examples:
$d=1$: $(a,b,c,d)=(27,1,1,1)$,
$d=4$: $(a,b,c,d)=(23,1,1,4)$,
$d=7$: $(a,b,c,d)=(19,1,1,7)$,
$d=10$: $(a,b,c,d)=(15,1,1,10)$,
$d=13$: $(a,b,c,d)=(11,1,1,13)$,
$d=16$: $(a,b,c,d)=(7,1,1,16)$,
$d=19$: $(a,b,c,d)=(3,1,1,19)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $a,b,c,d\ge 1$.

Since 
$$3a+6b+9c+4d=100\tag1$$$$\iff d=3(33-a-2b-3c-d)+1$$

$d$ can be written as $d=3e-2$ where $e$ is a positive integer.

So, 
$$(1)\iff 3a+6b+9c+12e-8=100\iff a+2b+3c+4e=36\tag2$$

Here, since $a\ge 1,2b\ge 2,3c\ge 3$,
$$4e=36-a-2b-3c\le 36-1-2-3=30\Rightarrow 1\le e\le 7.$$

For each $e$ such that $1\le e\le 7$, $(a,b,c)=(1,16-2e,1)$ satisfies $(2)$.

Hence, $e$ can take $7$ values. So $d$ can take $7$ values : $d=1,4,7,10,13,16,19$.

---

Assuming that $a,b,c,d\ge 0$, $d$ can take $9$ values since $(a,b,c,d)=(0,2,0,22),(0,0,0,25)$ satisfy $(1)$.